# Proving any finite non-empty set of real numbers has a max and a min.

Tags: real-analysis

My proof goes as follows:

Let S be a finite non-empty set of real numbers with exactly n elements. Assume by contradiction that S does not a max value.

That is, for every element in S there exists another element in S that is strictly greater than it.

Note that these two must be distinct since the latter will be strictly greater than the former.

Now, choose any element in S, and denote it by x_1. By our assumption, there is a distinct element in S strictly greater than x_1, which we denote by x_2.

Continuing in this fashion, for x_n-1 in S, there is x_n in S strictly greater than x_n-1. However, by our assumption there will also exist x_n+1 in S strictly greater than X_n.

Since x_n+1 cannot be x_n and since S has exactly n elements, then x_n+1 must be one of the following: x_1 , x_2, ..... x_n-1. However, these are all strictly less than x_n. So, this is impossible. That is, we have a contradiction in any case.

The case for the min value of S follows similarly.

My questions are

1. Is this proof correct?
2. How do I formalize it? Assuming this isn't rigorous enough.

Comment: A non-empty set of *what*?

Comment: Elements from what kind of set? Totally ordered? Poset? Lattice?

Comment: You should add the word $finite$ to your title.

Comment: You might need to prove that if $A$ is a finite set with $n$ elements then it can not be a finite set with $m;m \ne n$ elements.  Or that a set can't be both finite and infinitely countable.  Or simply a set must have one specific cardinality and not two.  Also twice you seem to claim elements are distinct because they are strictly greater.  It's enough to say they are distinct because elements of sets are distinct by definition.

Comment: You can sort the numbers, so it is obvious that the set must have a minimum and a maximum (which coincide in the case the numbers are all equal)

Comment: A slight simplification of your proof: if $S$ is a non-empty subset of $\mathbb{R}$ with no maximum element, define $f \colon \mathbb{N} \to S$ recursively by choosing $f(0)$ arbitrarily and $f(n+1)$ any element strictly greater than $f(n)$. By induction on $n$, $f(m) < f(n)$ whenever $m < n$, therefore $f$ is injective, therefore $S$ is infinite.